# Trying to display values from 2 text inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, arraylist, expo

I'm trying to display values from 2 text input and an image array (expo image picker) every time the text and images have been added like a todo app. I get no errors when i add the data, but the display view is empty (does not show any data added). here's the code:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
    const [photoArray, setPhotoArray] = useState([]);

    const [storeItems, setStoreItems] = useState([]);

    const addItem = [
        name, 
        price
    ]
    
    const addStoreItem = () => {
        setStoreItems([...storeItems, addItem])
        setName(null);
        setPrice(null);
    };

    const deleteItem = (index) => {
        let removeItem = [...storeItems, addItem];
        removeItem.splice(index, 1);
        setStoreItems(removeItem);
    }

    const pickPhoto = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
          allowsEditing: true,
          quality: 0.2,
        });
    
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setPhotoArray([...photoArray, result.uri]);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
<View style={styles.storeInput}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={addStoreItem}>
                        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                            <Image  source={icons.add} style={styles.icon}/>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View >
                        <FormStoreInput
                            placeholder={'Item Name'}
                            onChange={setName}
                            value={name}
                        />
                        <FormStoreInput 
                            placeholder={'Item Price'}
                            onChange={setPrice}
                            value={price}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View>
```

And i map the data here:

```
                    {
                        storeItems.map((_, index) => {
                            return (
                                <AddStoreItem key={index} name={name} price={price}/>
                            )
                        })
                    }
```

I'm new to this so please help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not showing up is because you aren't doing anything with the data in your map function. Map function signature is `map(value, index)`. In your case, your map function should be something like so

```
{
    storeItems.map((value, index) => {
        const [name, price] = value
        return (
            <AddStoreItem key={index} name={name} price={price}/>
        )
    })
}
```

The reason for destructuring value is because your storeItems is an array of arrays, and you can't just use the array directly.